# Set SQL Server name in connection string not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Formselectserver` where get the name of a SQL Server from a combobox. Also I have `form2` where is main form.

I send `combobox.selectedvalue` to connection string in form2 but that does not work.

I want user select one SQL Server in network and connect to it.

```
Formselectserver objfrmserver = new Formselectserver();

private const string strconnection = 
    @"server='" + objfrmserver.cmbshowallsqlserver.SelectedValue + 
    "';database = anfd; Integrated Security = SSPI";
```

The error is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'exportdatafromholoo.Form1.objfrmserver'

Answer (score 5):

Two things are wrong:

- A const values HAS to be resolved during compile time, not during runtime. You are using a runtime value. Just remove the `const`.
- Your field is a private field, so it is a member of your class. Is your `objfrmserver` also a member of that same class? You cannot initialize fields in the same class with each other. Move your initialization to the constructor.

Try this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    Formselectserver objfrmserver = new Formselectserver();
    string strconnection = @"server='" + objfrmserver.cmbshowallsqlserver.SelectedValue + "';database = anfd; Integrated Security = SSPI";
}
```

Comment: how to use SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(strconnection);

Comment: SqlConnection not reconize strconnection.

Comment: SqlConnection is not mentioned in your code. I do want to help you, but please show us all the code.

Comment: Than you should not ask me, but ask Marc. But to help you: put `using System.Data.SqlClient` in the top of your file.

Answer (score 4):

A `const` is a compile-time constant, so can only involve things that are known at compile-time - basically, literals.

`objfrmserver` is an instance (per-object) field that is a reference to another object, at runtime. This will not work. So basically, your `strconnection` cannot be a `const`. I suspect there's also not much purpose in it being a field. But as a *variable* it might make sense, i.e.

```
public void Connect() {
      var strconnection = @"server='" + objfrmserver.cmbshowallsqlserver.SelectedValue + "';database = anfd; Integrated Security = SS=PI";
      var conn = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
      conn.Open();
      // etc...
}
```

You might also want to look at `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, to avoid having to know the escaping rules associated with server-names.